# How are function parameters passed in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a high memory usage container datatype with some functions working on it, none of which ever traverses the whole container. However, if I want to apply those functions, I need to copy these unchanged data chunks from the parameters into the result. Most of my functions look something like this:

```
doStuff :: Container -> a -> Container 
doStuff container x = Container { 
    field1 = field1 container,
    field2 = myFunction $ field1 container,
    ...
    }
```

My Question is: Is field1 updated by passing a reference to its location or are the contents of field1 copied into the location of the resulting Container?

It is important to know because I build this whole datatype for efficiency purposes which would be vanished if the Container contents would be copied by my functions.

Comment: We need to see the definition of the `Container` type

Comment: Unless fields are declared strict, it will be lazily. That is `myFunction` will not even be called until `field2` is demanded.

Comment: @luqui does the field1 function actually touch its argument or just pass a reference? if I have a List of 1000000 elements in field1, would the method which just passes field1 need 1000000 steps for evaluation?

Comment: @dfeuer something like data Container = Container {field1::type1, field2:type2, etc.}. I obviously generalized my actual functions so I can formulate my question more clearly, but I‘m sorry if that makes it more difficult to anwer.

Comment: You would need to profile your code to find out. In theory, because everything is immutable, data that you would otherwise think of as copies can be implemented as shared references.

Comment: A lot of lazy updates (applying a function lazily to a record field) can definitely drive up memory use. Record fields should *usually* be strict, but it depends somewhat on their types and how they're used.

Comment: By the way you can experiment with this using `undefined`.  If `undefined` is ever "touched" the program will blow up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All comments below apply to GHC.

Except in special circumstances (read: where the programmer has explicitly requested it), constructing the new `Container` will involve a single pointer copy for `field1`. The `field2` equation will create a thunk referencing the computation `myFunction $ field1 container`; when that thunk is forced, it will proceed by passing a pointer (the same pointer as before!) to `myFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use record update syntax:

```
doStuff container = container { field2 = myFunction .... }
```

This creates a copy of `container` with just one field, `field2`, holding a different value. But the values in all the other fields in both containers will actually be the same values, shared between the two containers.

Evidence in GHCi:

```
> data Container = Container {field1::[Int], field2::[Int]} deriving Show
data Container = Container {field1 :: [Int], field2 :: [Int]}
field1 :: Container -> [Int]
field2 :: Container -> [Int]

> doStuff container = container { field2 = (++ [1]) $ field2 container }
doStuff :: Container -> Container

> xs=filter even [0..10::Int]

> :sprint xs
xs = _

> take 2 xs
[0,2]

> :sprint xs
xs = 0 : 2 : _

> doStuff (Container xs [0])
Container {field1 = [0,2,4,6,8,10], field2 = [0,1]}

> :sprint xs
xs = [0,2,4,6,8,10]
```

As we can see, `xs` was passed as if "by reference". There's no copying, i.e. no creation of the new list storage to hold the same values -- only a pointer to the list is used, as usual.

Another example to support the above claim:

```
> c1 = Container (filter even [0..20::Int]) ([0])
c1 :: Container

> c2 = doStuff c1
c2 :: Container

> :sprint c1
c1 = <Ghci39.Container> _ [0]

> :sprint c2
c2 = _

> take 2 $ field1 c2
[0,2]

> :sprint c2
c2 = <Ghci39.Container> (0 : 2 : _) _

> :sprint c1
c1 = <Ghci39.Container> (0 : 2 : _) [0]
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what this proves. It certainly proves that `xs` wasn't mutated, which is good since we're doing purely functional stuff. But as for call style, I fail to see how your GHC session demonstrates anything about pass by value vs. reference.

Comment: `doStuff` makes new container with a changed field, which is then printed, so its `field1`'s list gets fleshed out fully by the printing operation. Yet `xs` which was used in the original container is now fleshed out as well, as evidenced by the last `:sprint` command (and it wasn't, before). Ergo, it's the same list object, shared between the two containers.

Comment: If `xs` was copied, then it would be have to be fully fleshed out during the copy to get all the "new" elements. I feel like `xs` has to be fully evaluated, no matter which call strategy is used.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Your intuition turned out to be wrong, as is easily seen. I've added another example to that effect. The same lazy value is shared among the two data values.